# Migration from Java 8 to Java 17 And Spring 6 JUnit4 failing due to version mismatch

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm migrating an enterprise product. The things I have migrated are as follows:

- JDK 1.8 to JDK 17
- Spring 5.2.2.RELEASE to Spring 6.0.0

Now, in the process of migration, some tests have started to fail.

I have the below dependencies which are in older versions. I have tried to upgrade the versions but it's somehow not working.

Can someone please advise on which version needs to be there to resolve the test cases failures?

**pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Test Failure Log:**

```
ClassATest.initializationError » Objenesis java.lang...
ClassBTest.initializationError » Objenesis java.lang.refl...

Running com.util.SupportMonitoringUtilTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.util.SupportMonitoringUtilTest
initializationError(com.util.SupportMonitoringUtilTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl loaded by org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader @752573df cannot access jdk/internal/reflect superclass jdk.internal.reflect.MagicAccessorImpl
```

Comment: Go in the `surefire` folder or elsewhere to get the complete stacktrace of your failing test. We need to see what's follow the `java.lang.IllegalAccessError`: what its "caused by" is. The problem it faces. Often, going from Java 8 to 11 or 17 it's encountering modules no more available or needing to be made accessible again by some `--add-opens` or `--add-exports` options on the `java` command line.

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456726/mockclassloader-cannot-access-jdk-internal-reflect-superclass-jdk-internal-refle

Comment: This is the error traced from surefire-report directory
org.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl loaded by org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader @7e4204e2 cannot access jdk/internal/reflect superclass jdk.internal.reflect.MagicAccessorImpl

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of Mockito. Mockito 1.10.19 is positively ancient (the latest version is 5.2.0, note that the artifactId changed to mockito-core), and unlikely to work with recent versions of Java. The same probably goes for Powermock.

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Can you share your codebase please for testing?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
   <version>5.9.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency> <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.6.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.9</version>

     <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.9</version>

Comment: @AnishB. Am i using the correct version for Java 17 and Spring 6.0.0 or need to change ?

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY I guess I found the solution. Just adding now the answer.

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Your code is having tests in Junit 4 right? Why are you adding Junit 5 dependencies? Please remove that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade/add the following dependencies for **PowerMock** & **Mockito** to support **JDK 17**:

- Newer version of `powermock-module-junit4` needs to be added. Update `powermock-module-junit4` from `1.6.6` to `2.0.9` (which is the latest version at the time of writing the answer).
- Newer version of `powermock-api-mockito` needs to be added. Update `powermock-api-mockito (1.6.6)` to `powermock-api-mockito2 (2.0.9)` (which is the latest version at the time of writing the answer).
- Newer version of `javassist` needs to be added. Update `javassist` version to the latest version `(3.29.2-GA)` (at the time of writing the answer).

**Note:** You might face this error while running the tests on JDK 17:

```
Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module
```

To avoid this, you will need to tell maven by adding this `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` via `maven-surefire-plugin` when running this.

**Another point to be noted:** You don't need to add Mockito dependency separately. `powermock-api-mockito2` comes with the `mockito-core` dependency.

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-2</name>
    <description>Sample</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.29.2-GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This should work. I have tested on my local, it's working.

Sample codebase example for testing [here](https://github.com/anishb266/demo-2-1).

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY See if this helps.

Comment: Let me try this configuration.

Comment: Do i need any dependencies from below <!--  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
   <version>1.10.19</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>-->
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
<!--  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.6.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>-->

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Take all the dependencies and plugin from the pom.xml that I have provided and add your spring dependency and test.

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Don't add this mockito-all (1.10.19). I just tested now, it will throw error.

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY You will not need this mockito-all (1.10.19) in your pom.

Comment: After removing <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.6.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency> this dependencies I am executing only single test class by this command  mvn test -Dtest=XyzServiceImplTest

Comment: Getting this error -> 
XyzServiceImplTest.setUp:99 » NoSuchMethod 'java.lang.Object org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.newCheckedInstanceOfProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)'

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Can you do mvn clean install and try again

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY can you provide a minimum reproducable codebase. I can quickly resolve it.

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY I guess this error is generated from log4j. You have to add log4j latest dependency I guess.

Comment: Can you please share the test cases which you have wrote, I will run them in my env and try, if it works.

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY OK.

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY I have updated my answer with the code. Kindly look at it.

Comment: Kindly share the import statement too.

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Updated.

Comment: import static org.mockito.Mockito.times; Cannot resolve method 'verifyStatic(Class<Demo>, VerificationMode)'

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Forgot to add that import. Updating now.

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Done. Check now.

Comment: No Luck. java: no suitable method found for verifyStatic(java.lang.Class<com.visa.vrm.Demo>,org.mockito.verification.VerificationMode)
    method org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.verifyStatic() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.verifyStatic(org.mockito.verification.VerificationMode) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: Getting this error only - > Cannot resolve method 'verifyStatic(Class<Demo>, VerificationMode)'

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Did you add this ->. import static org.mockito.Mockito.times; ?

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY This is my repository try it on the local : https://github.com/anishb266/demo-2-1

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Is it working now?

Comment: Your code is working without any issue, but same configuration didn't work in my code base. I will post the errors today

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Great :) Post the error. But if you share a minimum reproducable codebase to fix. You can update my repo with the code having error. I will take a pull and have a look and fix it if possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255587/discussion-between-kuldeep-choudhary-and-anish-b).

Comment: Few errors I have from my project only so marking question as a acceptable. Thanks a lot